Why do the bottom boards break first? (when there are four without spacers)
In karate board breaking, I was told that the bottom boards always break first. I have observed this seems to be true.
The lighter and/or less experienced students breaking boards always broke the bottom boards first.
There were no spacers in these board breaking tests, which started with four boards directly stacked on top of each other.
Is this the result of Newton's third law?

Could this simply be because the bottom boards have space under them to 'break into'?

Related.

If it were one solid board, the same thickness as the stack of four, then you should expect the break to begin on the bottom side. That's where the material is under tension. Maybe Friction between the four boards under the force of the blow is enough to bind them together so that they are strained as if they were one, solid unit.

All About Torque
I don't exactly get what you mean by "no spacers" but I think that it is due to the torque that the bottom object is subjected to.
Let's think of a scenario where we (the observer) are looking at a setup perfectly horizontally (as if the setup is 2d) and there are two boards (both having a length of x meters) stacked perfectly on top of each other placed on top of two infinitely small supporting columns. The columns are placed so that the distance between them is x meters as well.
If someone was to apply a force of N newtons to the point x/2 on the top board it would only be a force equal to N newtons since the top plate doesn't have any pivot point and therefore is not subject to torque. But the same force would have torque on the bottom plate as there is a pivot exactly x/2 meters away. So the bottom plate would be subject to Nx/2 newton meters of torque.
This is the same reason as to why, let's say, a stick held from both ends would be easiest to break in the middle. It's all about torque.
Hope this helps

Thank you for answering my question. What I mean by "spacers" is that there are no spaces or gaps in-between the boards. They are completely touching each other.

I'm inclined to think that the dynamics of this phenomenon is closely analogous to the dynamics of a demonstration device usually referred to as 'Newton's cradle'
That wikipedia article has multiple animations.
Hypothesis:
Let's say a hit transfers just enough momentum to break one board.
The momentum is transferred to the top board, which transfers it to the second board. The process of transferring momentum from the top board to the second board then depletes the momentum of the top board, and the amount of momentum left is not enough to break it.
Same story for board two to board three.
Board four: the amount of momentum transferred to it makes the fourth board bend so much that it breaks.

If that is indeed what is physically happening then that is very interesting. The middle of the board receives so much velocity that the amount of force required to decelerate that velocity is larger than the elasticity of the wood can provide.

Thank you for answering my question. Your answer is very interesting because the boards always break cleanly right down the middle.
